# how much time a function will take to run in python

Tags: python

i defined a function,say

```
def func1(id):
    ....
    logic
    dataframe2.to_sql(query)
    ....
```

which runs some operations and store the result in database

and i have a table in pandas dataframe which has id column in it,and about 1000 rows with distinct id's

i will be calling this function using .apply function.

```
df['id'].apply(func1)
```

which will take one id at a time and do operations and store it in database , and same will happen for all id in my dataframe.

Is there any way to calculate how much total time my function took to run
for all id's in df?

i was thinking maybe use `time` package and do smthing with it. but i am a beginner.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
main()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: @EdChum indeed! Why don't you vote to close? I just did.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I ran out of close votes, otherwise I would dupe hammer this

Comment: sorry didn't think of that. Working my way to the python gold badge but the path is long :)

Comment: @rassar that is not the canonical duplicate of this question, in fact that question is a dupe of the one I posted, in principle we should close questions that are duplicates to avoid multiple posts as this just adds noise to SO

Answer (score 0):

you also can use context manager to check it. it could save some time when you want to reuse it.

```
>>> class TimeMyFunc(object):
...      def __enter__(self):
...          self.begin = time.time()
...      def __exit__(self,*args):
...          elapsed = time.time() - self.begin
...          print elapsed
...          
>>> with TimeMyFunc():
...     time.sleep(1)
...     
1.0
```